# React: Big Calendar Event Text

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I have this code that use the react-big-calendar, i need to modify the text that is visualized into the container but use EventDisplay broke the style of the container. Even if i delete the calculateEventStyle the container remains broken and does not fill all the cells reserved to the event. I need help.
There aren't errors is a problem of visualization, this is the picture of how it looks like removing EventDisplay and in this scenario the style works

Here the image, i was not able to load it on stackOverflow

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14aBey9l9TiW3hCv9IVpqfnB5r7iZxzMb/view?usp=sharing

But i want just the title visible on the container of the event

````
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from "react-big-calendar";
import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css";
import moment from "moment";
import "../Css/Calendar.css";
import axios from "axios";

var endpoint = "http://localhost:5000/tasks";

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

const messages = {
  previous: "←",
  next: "→",
  today: "Today",
  month: "Month",
  week: "Week",
  day: "Day",
  date: "Date",
  time: "Time",
};

//a way to modify the visualizzation of the event

const WeeklyCalendar: React.FC = () => {
  const startingHour = 8;
  const timeGutterFormat = "H:mm";
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const localUser = localStorage.getItem("user");

  const EventDisplay = ({ event }) => {
    return (
      <div className="custom-event" style={event.style}>
        {event.title}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const calculateEventStyle = (event) => {
    const durationInMinutes = (event.end - event.start) / (1000 * 60);
    const height = durationInMinutes * 2; // Adjust this multiplier as needed
    return {
      style: {
        height: `${height}px`,
        backgroundColor: "black",
      },
    };
  };

  //request to get the list of tasks related to the current user
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/tasks", {
        params: {
          user: localUser,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const tasks = response.data;

        const formattedEvents: Task[] = tasks.map((task: any) => ({
          title: task.title,
          start: new Date(task.start),
          end: new Date(task.end),
        }));

        setEvents(formattedEvents);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  console.log("EVENTS \n ", events, "\n");
  return (
    <div className="weekly-calendar-container">
      <Calendar
        localizer={localizer}
        defaultView="week" // Specify the default view
        startAccessor="start"
        endAccessor="end"
        min={new Date().setHours(startingHour, 0, 0, 0)} //setta la prima ora visualizzata nel calendario
        style={{ height: 600, width: 1000 }}
        events={events}
        formats={{
          timeGutterFormat,
        }}
        messages={messages}
        components={{
          eventWrapper: EventDisplay,
        }}
        eventPropGetter={calculateEventStyle}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default WeeklyCalendar; ``` 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbFkn.png
````

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and show the debugging details

Comment: there are no errors just a visualization problem, i add also a screenshot of the actual look of the calendar

Answer (score 0):

An `EventWrapper` is just that: a wrapper

```js
const EventDisplay = ({children, ...props}) => (
  <div {...props}>{children}</div>
);
```

To customize the *content* of an `Event` you would override the `Event` component, typically at the `view` level, as the 'month' view `Event` layout differs from a `TimeGrid` (day or week view) `Event`, which differs from an `Agenda` view `Event`.

```js
const components = {
  week: {
    event: CustomEvent
  }
};
```

But, what it really looks like you are trying to do is add a custom className and styles to an event display. For this, you want to use the [eventPropGetter](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/docs/props--event-prop-getter) prop, providing a method to dynamically apply classes and styles to your events.

```js
const eventPropGetter = (event: Object, start: Date, end: Date, isSelected: boolean) => Object
```

From your `eventPropGetter` method you return an object containing optional key/values of `className`s and/or an object of `style`s. You can dynamically decide which classes and/or styles to include, for a particular event, based upon values from any of the arguments of the method.

So, say your `event` object included a key for a clinics, and you wanted to change the background color of the event based on what clinic the event was assigned to.

```js
const colors = {
  1: 'green',
  2: 'blue',
  3: 'yellow',
  4: 'red'
};

const eventPropGetter = ({clinic}) => ({
  style: {
    ...(colors[clinic] && { backgroundColor: colors[clinic] })
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could be more clear. It has been some time since question asked, but I want to add that **setting a height for the event is not right**
. It will be calculated by the Calendar component. **Providing start and end date will enough to let it cover how much space it will take.**